# Где можно скачать OpenGL последней версии и GLSL?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glsl

Пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на исходные файлы на языке C++ и сборку (`.dll`, `.lib`).

Comment: @___, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтоп.

Answer (score 7):

Вопрос некорректный. OpenGL это всего лишь спецификация он отсутствует в виде набора драйверов или отдельного SDK.

Драйвера поставляются с графической картой, SDK для каждой платформы и графической карты разные и зависят от производителя. Для карт серии ATI SDK Open GL ES лежит [здесь](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/)

Comment: Неужели нет универсальных решений, на подобие того, как это сделано для веб-браузеров, jre, и т.п. ...?

Comment: Реализация спецификации OpenGL сильно зависит от видеокарты. И только разработчики видеокарт могут реализовать функциональность OpenGL. Т.к. не существует универсального драйвера для видеокарт, так и не существует универсальной реализации для OpenGL. Насчёт jre и веб-браузеров, они выпускаются под определённые платформы, например для MacOSX и  Windows инсталляторы разные. Также если кому-то понадобилось выпускать jre для ARM, RISC то это были бы другие бинарники.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что `OpenGL` это спецификация. Реализации данной спецификации как правило занимается поставщик драйверов для вашей видеокарте. Например для видео карты NVidea драйвера можно найти [тут](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver). Так же вы можете увидеть там список поддерживаемых `OpenGL` расширений.

Судя по указанным вам расширениям библиотек, вы собираетесь писать под ос `Windows`. В операционной системе `Windows` `OpenGL ABI` был заморожен в версии 1.1, это значит, что эта операционная система из коробки предоставляет чуть больше, чем ничего для работы с `OpenGL`. В прочем это не значит, что на винде нельзя получить доступ к новейшим функциям OpenGL'a. Чаще всего эту проблему решают с помощью использования библиотеки `GLEW`. Однако использование этой библиотеки значит таскать за собой кучу ненужного. Эта библиотека содержит все функции которые когда либо входили в `OpenGL`, а если вы хотите использовать функции `OpenGL 4.x`, то вам явно не нужны функции от других версий. Что бы избежать все этих неприятностей можно воспользоваться утилитой `OpenGL Loader Generator`, скачать можно [тут](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/downloads).

Для того, что бы воспользоваться утилитой, нужно установить `LUA`, скачать можно [тут](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows/releases).

Сгенерировать файлы для нужного вам профиля можно следующей командой:

```
lua LoadGen.lua -style=pointer_cpp -spec=gl -version=4.3 -profile=core core_4_3
```

Описание всех доступных аргументов можно найти [тут](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Command_Line_Options).

В папке с утилитой появится файл: `gl_core_4_3.hpp`  и `gl_core_4_3.cpp`

Теперь достаточно добавить эти 2 файла в проект, что бы больше не таскать с собой GLEW, а так же избавиться от проблемы связанной с переборкой GLEW по разные версии.

Доступ к функциях в сформированных файлах будет осуществляться из пространства имен gl, т.е. вместо `glBufferData(..)`  нужно будет записать `gl::BufferData(..)`.

Что бы в существующем проекте не вносить кучу правок, можно воспользоваться С-шным стилем оформления, для этого достаточно утилите передать другой стиль:

```
lua LoadGen.lua -style=pointer_c -spec=gl -version=4.3 -profile=core core_4_3
```

Для загрузки функций в cpp варианте, нужно написать следующий код:

```
gl::exts::LoadTest isLoaded = gl::sys::LoadFunctions();
if(!isLoaded ){
    // освободить ресурсы
    return;
}
```

`С` вариант:

```
int loaded = ogl_LoadFunctions();
if(loaded == ogl_LOAD_FAILED){
    // освободить ресурсы
    return;
}
```

Автоматическая загрузка функций

`GlLoadGen` так же поддерживает автоиницилизиацию указателей. Этот режим можно включить с помощью передачи параметров в утилиту `noload_c` или `noload_cpp` в параметр `-style`. Включение этих параметров позволит избежать необходимости инициализации, но такой вариант влечет за собой небольшие накладные расходы на инициализацию функций, которая происходит при первом вызове.

Использование расширений

Если вы хотите использовать какие то расширения, то вам потребуется их подключить явно указав их имя через параметр `-extfile`. Пример:

```
lua LoadGen.lua -style=pointer_cpp -spec=gl -version=4.3 -profile=core core_4_3 -exts ARB_texture_view ARB_vertex_attrib_binding
```